# Connect to PostgreSQL from SpringBootApplication

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, maven

I am building a simple Spring application from the scratch using Maven and PostgreSQL.

I've been following thousand of tutorials but it isn't clear for me where to store the different configurations to connect and work with a PostgreSQL database.

My `pom.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>gs-rest-service</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.0</version>

  <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
          <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
          <version>9.4-1201-jdbc4</version>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <properties>
      <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>


  <build>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>

  <repositories>
      <repository>
          <id>spring-releases</id>
          <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
      </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
      <pluginRepository>
          <id>spring-releases</id>
          <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
      </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

My `src/main/java/quotes/Application.java` file:

```
package quotes;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

My `src/main/java/quotes/Quote.java` file:

```
package quotes;

public class Quote {

    private String content;
    private String author;

    public Quote(String content, String author) {
        this.content = content;
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return this.content;
    }

    public Quote setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
        return this;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return this.author;
    }

    public Quote setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
        return this;
    }
}
```

And my `src/main/java/quotes/QuoteController.java` file:

```
package quotes;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;

@Controller
public class QuoteController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @RequestMapping("/random")
    public @ResponseBody Quote randomQuote() {
        return new Quote("¿A dónde vas? Patatas traigo", "Ortega y Pacheco");
    }

}
```

I can build and run the application with Maven:

```
mvn clean package
java -jar target/*.jar
```

The idea now is to modify the code on `QuoteController.java` to connect to PostgreSQL and return a random stored quote.

Could you please give some advices / clues?

Comment: Search for Spring Data tutorials.

Comment: I promise I did. I am getting crazy here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this tutorial .

http://devcrumb.com/hibernate/spring-data-jpa-hibernate-maven

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an application.properties file under src/main/resources

It should look like this for PostgreSQL:

```
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.database.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/your-db-name
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
```

Checkout this link for more info:

[enter link description here](http://www.javabeat.net/spring-boot-sql-databases/)